# Add angle symbol to string

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder, c++builder-10.3-rio

How can i add an [angle symbol](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2220) to a string to put in a `TMemo`?

I can add a degree symbol easy enough based on its octal value from the [extended ascii table](https://www.ascii-code.com/):

```
String deg = "\272";  // 272 is octal value in ascii code table for degree symbol
Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add("My angle = 90" + deg);
```

**But, if i** try to use the escape sequence for the angle symbol (`\u2220`) i get a compiler error, `W8114 Character represented by universal-character-name \u2220 cannot be represented in the current ansi locale`:

```
UnicodeString deg = "\u2220";
Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add("My angle = 90" + deg);
```

Just for clarity, below is the symbol i'm after.  I can just use the `@` if i have too, just wondering if this is possible without nashing of teeth.  My target for this test was Win32 but i'll want it to work on iOS and Android too.

[image]

p.s.  [This table](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/unicode-characters.html) is handy to see the codes.

**After** following Rob's answer i've got it working but on iOS the angle is offset down below the horizontal with the other text. On Win32 it is tiny.  Looks good on Android.  I'll report as a bug to Embarcadero, albeit minor.

[image: results]

[image: android result]

Here is code i used based on Rob's comments:

```
UnicodeString szDeg;
UnicodeString szAng;
szAng.SetLength(1);
szDeg.SetLength(1);
*(szAng.c_str()) = 0x2220;
*(szDeg.c_str()) = 0x00BA;
Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add("1: " + FormatFloat("##,###0.0",myPhasors.M1)+ szAng + FormatFloat("###0.0",myPhasors.A1) + szDeg);
```

Here is how looks when explicitly set the `TMemo` font to Courier New:

[image: after setting font to Courier New]

Here is the final code i'm using after Remy's replies:

```
UnicodeString szAng = _D("\u2220");         
UnicodeString szDeg = _D("\u00BA");
Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add("1: " + FormatFloat("##,###0.0",myPhasors.M1)+ szAng + FormatFloat("###0.0",myPhasors.A1) + szDeg);
```

Comment: that is unicode not ASCII nor extended ASCII. I am usually using  `charmap` app to get the character into clipboard and paste it into code as string ... but I am on old IDE from 2006 without unicode support ... but for stuff I use it works anyway suspect it encode string as UTF8

Comment: The offset of the symbol in the display has nothing to do with FireMonkey itself, but with the Font being used.

Comment: Initially the font family for the `TMemo` was just (default).  I explicitly set it to Courier New just now and put the results in my question above.  I'm not understanding this as a Font problem - it looks great on Android, ok on Win32 but small, good on iOS but offset terribly below horizontal.  I thought Courier New was a proportional font and i can't see how this offset is occuring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler error is because you are using a narrow ANSI string literal, and `\u2220` does not fit in a `char`. Use a Unicode string literal instead:

```cpp
UnicodeString deg = _D("\u2220");
```

The RTL's `_D()` macro prefixes the literal with either the `L` or `u` prefix depending on whether `UnicodeString` uses `wchar_t` (Windows only) or `char16_t` (other platforms) for its character data.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates some kind of code range failure, which you ought to be able to avoid.  Try setting the character code directly:

```cpp
UnicodeString  szDeg;
UnicodeString  szMessage;

  szDeg.SetLength(1);
  *(szDeg.c_str())=0x2022;

  szMessage=UnicodeString(L"My angle = 90 ")+szDeg;
  Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add(szMessage);
```

Comment: That works, thanks Rob!  It displays little weird on iOS - i've updated my question to show.  Anyway, it is close enough for what i'm doing.

Comment: You can and should use `szDeg[1]=0x2022;` instead of `*(szDeg.c_str())=0x2022;`